# How to expand member-variables in Write-Host or double quotes?

Tags: powershell

I have written a PS script and for diagnostic purpose am echoing messages to screen using Write-Host. This is fine as long as I have to expand normal variable like

> `Write-Host "Hello World, $name"`

Problem starts when i try to echo some member variable as below

```
Write-Host "Hello World, $Person.Name"
```

This does not expand as expected. The work around that am following is, to use temp variable
as below

```
$personName  = $Person.Name
Write-Host "Hello World, $personName"
```

Is there an elegant way of doing this with out the use of temp variable?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

If you want to use property access within double-quoted strings, you need a subexpression:

```
"Foo $($bar.Property)"
```

Comment: @IdoRan: Not to my knowledge or testing: `$s='foo'; "$s.Length"` → `foo.Length` (PS v5.1). I'd also find it unlikely that they would change those rules, as that's not very nice compatibility-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$dir = ls
Write-Host "Dir elements:" $dir.Length
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that is that if you change to Write-Output and redirect to a file, the text will be broken up into two output lines.  The accepted answer avoids this problem.